# How to Reset Config.h

Tags: dwm

I've made a lot changes to my config files over time and I was wondering how I could revert them back to their default settings (with the current patches in mind)? I want to reset some changes I've made, so having an untouched config file would be helpful

So, if I have for example, vanitygaps installed, how could I get an unmodified `config.h` with the default vanitygaps settings included?

I know I could just recompile dwm with the patches, but I was wondering if there was an faster way. Thanks.

Edit: I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: Worth mentioning which distro you're using, as the answer might involve use of the relevant package manager.

Comment: Do you commit your changes to git or something like it?

Comment: @icarus I hadn't committed the original versions, I should have, but, only started doing that after I had changed the configs a bit.